# Background Subtraction in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am trying to subtract two images using absdiff function ,to extract moving object, it works good but sometimes background appears in front of foreground.
This actually happens when the background and foreground colors are similar,Is there any solution to overcome this problem?
It may be description of the problem above not enough; so I attach images in the following 
[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz6MObtH-KRAZGhaSjduNzlVOUE) .
Thanks..

Comment: How can you determine background from only two images? Do you only have 2 images or do you have more? Specifically, I'm wondering if you are working on videos or images.

Comment: I am working on videos. for each frame, I have the original frame and an image from camera , I subtract them to extract moving object.

Comment: Why don't you simply do `moving average` or `gaussian mixture model`? How could you have the background/original image? It would be a biased experiment in that case, isn't it?

Comment: Actually camera is directed to projected image that I have .

Comment: Could you share images which works and which fails?

Comment: I did not think of GMM or any other because this function simply was sufficient -in my opinion- to find the moving object then deals with it.

Comment: Yes, you already have a well-defined background. no need to calculate background again. But I'd like to see why it fails. I can't comment without seeing an example. It feel like `absdiff` should work but I prefer to come up with conclusion after seeing an example.

Comment: sorry for being late . Give me a few minutes so that I can be uploaded images.

Comment: The original images are not there, however, the problem here is when background and foreground are similar colors, your algorithm considers those pixels as foreground and blacks out that index. This is a very advanced problem that can't be solved with basic solutions. (I don't know if any existing solution for this). One simple suggestion is to work on RGB rather than grayscale. Then you are likely to have a little less error

Comment: Well, I'll try that.thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use some pre-processing techniques like edge detection and some contrast stretching algorithm, which will give you some extra information for subtracting the image. Since color is same but new object should have texture feature like edge; if the edge gets preserved properly then when performing image subtraction you will obtain the object.

Process flow:

1. Use edge detection algorithm.
2. Contrast stretching algorithm(like histogram stretching).
3. Use the detected edge top of the contrast stretched image.
4. Now use the image subtraction algorithm from OpenCV.

Comment: I try what you have suggested ..I detected the edges using Sobel ,then applied Histogram Equalization. And tried versa.. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough information to formulate a complete solution to your problem but there are some tips I can offer:

- First, prefilter the input and background images using a strong
  median (or gaussian) filter. This will make your results much more
  robust to image noise and confusion from minor, non-essential detail
  (like the horizontal lines of your background image). Unless you want
  to detect a single moving strand of hair, you don't need to process
  the raw pixels.
- Next, take the advice offered in the comments to test all 3 color
  channels as opposed to going straight to grayscale.
- Then create a grayscale image from the the max of the 3 absdiffs done
  on each channel.
- Then perform your closing and opening procedure.

I don't know your requirements so I can't take them into account. If accuracy is of the utmost importance. I'd use the median filter on input image over gaussian. If speed is an issue I'd scale down the input images for processing by at least half, then scale the result up again. If the camera is in a fixed position and you have a pre-calibrated background, then the current naive difference method should work. If the system has to determine movement from a real world environment over an extended period of time (moving shadows, plants, vehicles, weather, etc) then a rolling average (or gaussian) background model will work better. If the camera is moving you will need to do a lot more processing, probably some optical flow and/or fourier transform tests. All of these things need to be considered to provide the best solution for the application.